# Why regex validation is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form with

```
<td class="label">@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Link)</td>
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Link)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Link)
</td>
```

The `Link` property has a `RegularExpression`

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(([^\:\/?#]+)\:)?(\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?$", ErrorMessage= "invalid URL")]
```

But it is not being validated. If I add `[Required]` the field is validated.

I'm including 3 scripts:

- jquery 1.5.2
- jquery.validate.min.js (default)
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js (default)

Do I need to include another script? Why it doesn't work for Regex?

Comment: it looks as if each part of the expression is optional (all those `?` after the captures/groupings, except for this one `([^?#]*)`, which is still optional because of the `*`), so an empty string would pass, and that's probably why you needed to use the `Required` attr. All in all Darin provided a much cleaner and easier to prove correct regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some error in the regex. Sorry, I can't spot it, regexes are a bit like Chinese to me (I know I am not helpful here)

I've tried the [following](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm) and it worked fine:

```
[RegularExpression(@"((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)", ErrorMessage = "invalid URL")]
```

Comment: Yes, something is messed up with that one. Yours worked, thank you.